# How to call Oracle statement with named bind variables and get result via JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have some old C code I'm moving to Java and I have to port along existing SQL functions into JDBC. The commands are written like this (two of many examples):

```
RESULT:=1 + ?
IF ? > 0 THEN RESULT:=0 ELSE RESULT:= 1; END IF;
```

Those are two examples (separate commands).
Changing the syntax of the commands isn't an option, but some clever runtime replacement is valid. Note the ? are values that will get populated at runtime from other data.

I've tried this as statements, prepared statements, and callable statements, and I can't seem to get the syntax correct for getting "RESULT" back (actually, can't get it to execute() on any statement.

For test purposes I've been trying a simple command of either:

```
RESULT:=1+2
RESULT:=1+?
```

Just to see if I can get the type of statement working. But no luck.

The most common answer, from code that otherwise looks reasonable, is this:

```
String queryString = "declare result integer; begin RESULT:= 1 + 3; ? := RESULT; end";
try (CallableStatement cst = conn.prepareCall(queryString))
{
    cst.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
    cst.execute();
}
```

When I run that, on the execute (or executeUpdate, doesn't make a difference) I get back an Oracle 17002/08006  (Size Data Unit mismatch, network issue / invalid connection). But I have to believe that error is somewhat of a red herring, because the connection is definitely valid, and a trivially statement works fine.

Does anyone know the correct JDBC approach to calling that and getting a valid result (out of RESULT)?

I'm using Java 7 and Oracle 11g, if it matters.

Comment: You haven't said why it doesn't work - what happens? Do you get an error? Showing your Java code (and maybe the C version for context) would help; I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. You seem to be setting a PL/SQL variable from a bind variable and then just trying to get it back, which seems a bit pointless, so I'm missing something.

Comment: Generally it gets errors on the execute() statement, varies depending on the code tried (or trying to bind "RESULT" as an out variable for a callable). Problem is it's clear to me anything I've tried is invalid - and potentially misleading from what's the correct method.

Comment: Your query string is incoorect. You should write a stored procedure and then use JDBC to call it from Java code. Then, you can simply call it as select your_procedure_name from dual;

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of calling a stored procedure that accepts an Integer argument and returns a single value (my Java method returns an Object and you can cast it to whatever you like).

```
public Object getResultFromStoredProcedure(String query,Integer param) {
    Object obj=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    PreparedStatement stmt=null;
    try{
        stmt=conn.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setInt(1,param);

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();   
        if(rs.next()){
            obj=rs.getObject(1);

        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        //catch exception and process it or log it
    }finally{
        rs.close();
        stmt.close()
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Provided that you called your procedure OrclProc, you'd call it thus

```
String query = "select OrclProc(?) from dual";    
Object result = getResultFromStoredProcedure(query, 5);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without creating each equation as a stored procedure? I have to run more than 100,000 of these, many very simple (like my example), many more complicated. I can easily compute all the inputs needed, and all assign a result to a bind variable named "RESULT". But I don't think I want to create that many stored procedures (I suppose I could re-use the name and redefine it)?

Comment: It would help if you explained exactly what you're trying to achieve. I assumed that you already have stored procedures and need to call them from Java.

Comment: my apologies if not clear. Essentially I have 100,000+ equations (from old software) in the format "RESULT := ..." or more complex (per the IF/THEN example in the original question) that I need to execute in new code (Java). Re-writing them isn't an option based on quantity. I've tried several things; the example code I included above seemed to be the closest to working, and looked to me basically correct based on some bind variable examples. But it's not working, and I'm lost on what to try next (was really hoping someone knows the "correct" approach to running this sort of thing).

Comment: It seems to me that you're trying to create pl/sql statements on the fly and execute them. I don't think that any JDBC driver supports that, though I'm not 100% sure. If the stored procedures already exist, then you can call them from Java. Of course , you can create stored procedures programmaticate with the create procedure statement and then call them like in my example above.